# What is the meaning of a set $E$ being closed under the intersection of this subsets of set $S$, where $E\subseteq 2^{S}-\{\emptyset\}$?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, set-theory

Suppose that $s$ is a random variable defined over some space $S$. Let $E\subseteq 2^{S}-\{\emptyset\}$ be a set of subsets of $S$ that is closed under the intersection.

What does $E$ represent with respect to $S$? Is it some kind of algebra? ($\sigma$, semi - algebra) or it just means that it contains for sure elements that belong to $S$?

Comment: $E$ will be a $\pi$-system: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi-system

Comment: the $\pi-$system that is generated by $S$?

Comment: How is the random variable related to $E$?

Comment: @ArcticChar there is a correspondence defined as $C:S\to E$ such that

$$C(s)=\{e\in E|s\in e\},\quad\text{for all $s\in S$}$$

Comment: Well it semms to me that the mappig $C$ is surjective, because for every $s$ there is  $e\in E$

Comment: maybe not........